# Why "propdp" code snippet doesn't use the nameof operator for the name of the registered property?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, dependency-properties, code-snippets

If you insert the snippet **propdp**, it doesn't use the **nameof** operator for the property name in the first parameter of the [DepencendyProperty.Register](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms597502(v=vs.110).aspx) method and it creates something like this:

```
    public string Text
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(TextProperty); }
        set { SetValue(TextProperty, value); }
    }

    // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for Text.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
    public static readonly DependencyProperty TextProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("Text", typeof(string), typeof(MyContentControl), new PropertyMetadata(""));
```

and obviusly can be better if you use the operator **nameof** like in the next example:

```
    public string Text
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(TextProperty); }
        set { SetValue(TextProperty, value); }
    }

    // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for Text.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
    public static readonly DependencyProperty TextProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register(nameof(Text), typeof(string), typeof(MyContentControl), new PropertyMetadata(""));
```

Comment: `nameof` is relatively new, and i'm not sure that the snippets are able to determine which version of C# your project is compiling too.  If you're working on both old and new c# projects, and the snippets are not able to determine which version of c# is being used, then that is probably a reason why. Keep the snippet supporting legacy so it works no matter what, rather than being "broken" sometimes (for older projects).

Comment: or it could have just been overlooked

Comment: Or create a new code snippet using nameof, for example "npropdp" to use in the case you're using C# 6.

Comment: This issue was reported to Microsoft here: [Update "propdp" snippet to use nameof](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/update-propdp-snippet-to-use-nameof/1046667) They since opened a Github issue to track the actual change: [#44551](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/44551) As of today (November 2021) it is still "open", over a year later. But it seems like eventually there is some chance it will get fixed in VS.

Comment: This seems like the current tracking issue: https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/5574

Answer (score 15):

You can modify the code snippet following the next steps:

- Locate the snippet's file. Select menu option **Tools/Code Snippets Manager...**. The Code Snippets Manager dialog box will show.
- In **Language**, select **CSharp**.
- Open NetFX30 and select **Define a Dependency Property**. You'll see the path of the file in **Location**. Should be in *C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC#\Snippets\1033\NetFX30*

Open the file and change the definition of the macro from

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty $property$Property = 
DependencyProperty.Register("$property$", typeof($type$), typeof($ownerclass$), new PropertyMetadata($defaultvalue$));
```

to

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty $property$Property = 
DependencyProperty.Register(nameof($property$) , typeof($type$), typeof($ownerclass$), new PropertyMetadata($defaultvalue$));
```

and save (remember to open your text editor as an administrator).

Restart Visual Studio.