# Why “propdp” code snippet doesn't propose the correct name of the class in where you're declaring the dependency property?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, code-snippets

When you create a dependency property using the **propdp** code snippet, it doesn't propose for you the correct name of the class in where you're creating the dependency property, and you've to type it manually like in the next example:

```
namespace YourApp.Controls
{
    public sealed class YourButton : Control
    {
        public YourButton()
        {
            this.DefaultStyleKey = typeof(YourButton);
        }

        public string Text
        {
            get { return (string)GetValue(TextProperty); }
            set { SetValue(TextProperty, value); }
        }

        // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for Text.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
        public static readonly DependencyProperty TextProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("Text", typeof(string), typeof(ownerclass), new PropertyMetadata(0));
    }
}
```

I don't want as a default value **ownerclass**, I want **YourButton** in this case.

How can I modify the code snippet to propose the correct name?

Answer (score 5):

Analyzing the source code of the **ctor** code snippet it's really easy to know the problem: you only have to add the next line:

```
<Function>ClassName()</Function>
```

in the definition of the literal ownerclass.

- Open the file C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC#\Snippets\1033\NetFX30\propdp.snippet.
- Add that line in the definition of the ownerclass.
- Save the file.
- Restart Visual Studio.

The file must be like this:

```
...
<Literal>
    <ID>ownerclass</ID>
    <ToolTip>The owning class of this Property.  Typically the class that it is declared in.</ToolTip>
    <Function>ClassName()</Function>
    <Default>ownerclass</Default>
</Literal>
...
```

And then you'll have what you want by default:

```
namespace YourApp.Controls
{
    public sealed class YourButton : Control
    {
        public YourButton()
        {
            this.DefaultStyleKey = typeof(YourButton);
        }

        public string Text
        {
            get { return (string)GetValue(TextProperty); }
            set { SetValue(TextProperty, value); }
        }

        // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for Text.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
        public static readonly DependencyProperty TextProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("Text", typeof(string), typeof(YourButton), new PropertyMetadata(0));
    }
}
```

Use the modification proposed in [Why "propdp" code snippet doesn't use the nameof operator for the name of the registered property?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35392084/why-propdp-code-snippet-doesnt-use-the-nameof-operator-for-the-name-of-the-re) to have it using the **nameof** operator.

Comment: I think there is no need for restarting VS, try this please.

Comment: Tested. You've to restart VS.